# Rewarded Video Ads - setting amount and type of reward

Tags: android, ads, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

I implemented showing rewarded video according to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video#initialize_rewarded_video_ads). When a reward video ad has triggered a reward then [`onRewarded(RewardItem reward)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener.html#onRewarded(com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem)) is called.
Where and how I can set the information about the reward that [RewardItem](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardItem) contains (the amount of credit and the type the credit) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to share what I've found. Reward amount and reward item can be set during creation of a rewarded video ad unit. Here are [instructions](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7311747?hl=en%20.) on how to create such ad unit and [more information](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7372450) about rewarded video ad units.